Auto increment string primary key with custom logic in sqlmodel
I have a sqlmodel class:
from typing import Optional, List
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel, UniqueConstraint

class Query(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[str] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    text: str = Field(default=None, unique=True)
    task: str 
    use_case: str

I would like to have an auto increment with custom logic, for example :
# latest_id is an int that increment
new_id = f'{task[0:3]}-{use_case[0:3]}-{latest_id}'

I can implement a helper function that create that id but I would like to have this logic inside the class.
Thank you

I'm not going to lie - SQLModel is something I've never heard of, but id: Optional[str] makes no sense to me. How can you have an optional primary key?

@roganjosh https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/automatic-id-none-refresh/

@Madaray ids are generated by database, not by the Python code. You do not set them on Python's side. Additionaly, using str in place of int as table's primary key requires some additional work (assuming you're using SQLite) and is probably not a good idea.

I see you point. Do you think that the technical key I want should be derived from the columns ? This technical key will not be stored in the database and will be generated from an auxiliary function ?

After some research, it seems that this is impossible.
My solution consists of an additional getter which generates a denormalized id.
